# Reverse Nodes in k-Group in linked list (two types of cases not working )

Tags: c++

```
ListNode* reverseKGroup(ListNode* head, int k) {
    if(head==NULL||k==1||head->next==NULL){
        return head;
    }
    
    ListNode *curr=head,*prev=NULL,*nex=NULL,*newHead;
    ListNode *t1=head,*t2=head;
    
    int count=0;
    while(curr->next!=NULL){
        curr=curr->next;
        count++;
        
    }
    int n=count;
    curr=head;
    while(count>=k){
        for(int i=1;i<=k;i++){
            nex=curr->next;
            curr->next=prev;
            prev=curr;
            curr=nex;
        }
        if(newHead==NULL) newHead=prev;
        if(t1!=t2)t1->next=prev;
        t2->next=curr;
        t1=t2;
        t2=curr;
        prev=NULL;
        count-=k;
        
    }
    if(prev==NULL) t1->next=curr;
    
    return newHead;
}
```

This above code is failing for 2 kinds of cases:

1.Your input

[1,2,3,4,5,6]   //(value of nodes of linked lists.)

3               //(3 is the k no of nodes u need to reverse group wise)

Output

[3,2,1,4,5,6]

Expected
[3,2,1,6,5,4]

2.Your input

[1,2]

2                  //(i.e. whenever k is the length of the entire linked list)

Output

error

Expected

[2,1]

I really appreciate any advice or help to correct this code so it works properly. (Thank You!)

Comment: In what way is it failing? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: `count` is off by one. E.g. for a list of two elements, `count == 1`. Then `while(count>=k)` check exits one iteration too early.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks a lot!! I realized my mistake and also one  more fault in the code

Answer (score 0):

```
ListNode* reverseKGroup(ListNode* head, int k) {
    if(head==NULL||k==1||head->next==NULL){
        return head;
    }
    
    ListNode *curr=head,*prev=NULL,*nex=NULL,*newHead;
    ListNode *t1=head,*t2=head;
    
    int count=0;               //Also my counter was 1 less than link list length 
    while(curr!=NULL){
        curr=curr->next;
        count++;
        
    }
    curr=head;
    while(count>=k){
        
        for(int i=1;i<=k;i++){
            nex=curr->next;
            curr->next=prev;
            prev=curr;
            curr=nex;
        }
        
        if(newHead==NULL) newHead=prev;
        if(t1!=t2)t1->next=prev;
        t2->next=curr;                 // I forgot to add next link of t2 to curr
        t1=t2;
        t2=curr;
        
        prev=NULL;
        count-=k;
    }
    
    
    return newHead;
}
```

I made 2 changes as commented in the code and now the code is working perfect with O(N) time complexity and 0(1) space complexity